# jquery remove first row in table

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery

I need to have a nice transition where I remove the first row and append to a table new item.

```
    $.getJSON('/Home/GetRecentPosts/', { count:1 }, function(data) {
      $('#recentPosts tr:first').fadeOut(2000);
      $('#recentPosts').append($('<tr><td>'+data[0].SchoolName+'</td></tr>').hide().fadeIn(2000));
    });
```

this works the first time i execute getJson only. Please help.
thanks

Comment: How/where are you calling this method? You don't perform any test on the `data` returned by the server, you are directly accessing `data[0]`. Is it guaranteed that every time the server sends a JSON collection containing at least one element?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've tried to separate each item of functionality you want onto a separate line. If this isn't what you are after, then hopefully it shouldn't be to hard to adjust the below code to suit your needs.

```
$.getJSON(
    '/Home/GetRecentPosts/',
    { count:1 },
      removeFirstRowAndAppendNewItem(data)
      );

function removeFirstRowAndAppendNewItem(data)
{
    console.log("in callback"); // to confirm we have reached here
    $('#recentPosts tr:first').fadeOut(2000, function() {
        $('#recentPosts tr:first').remove();
        newRow = $('<tr><td>'+data[0].SchoolName+'</td></tr>').hide();
        $('#recentPosts').append(newRow)
        newRow.fadeIn(2000));
    });
}
```

Basically:

- Fade out the first row
- Remove the first row from the DOM
- Create a new element, with styling that hides it
- Append the new element to the table
- Fade in the new element

(Note: it's possible to combine these steps together)

Comment: australis: is there a way to add a slideUp transition for the rest of the rows after the first has been removed to add a nicer effect? thanks

Comment: Shane: I could be mistaken, but I think the only way to slide a row is to embed a div into the row, and then slide that. Have you had any luck with this? if not i will try and dig up an example.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
$('#recentPosts tr:visible:first').fadeOut(2000);
```

Because

```
$('#recentPosts tr:first').fadeOut(2000);
```

would have hidden the first element at the first JSON call. Now you are trying again to fadeOut the invisible first element. So you could use a `:visible` filter to achieve the expected result.

Alternatively, if you wanna remove the element from DOM, try this

```
$('#recentPosts tr:first').fadeOut(2000, function(){
    $(this).remove();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$.ajax({
beforeSend: function(){
// Handle the beforeSend event
},
complete: function(){
// Handle the complete event
}
// ......
});
```